# Is it possible to create a new sheet in Smartsheet API without copying from an existing one

Tags: smartsheet-api

With Smartsheet API, I cannot find an API call to create a new sheet and define its columns directly. Is this possible and if so, how?  I'm using the cData FireDac component which is very friendly to SQL.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create a new sheet via the Smartsheet API. You can send a `POST` request to `/sheets` with a body that defines the column structure like this:

```
{
    "name":"newsheet",
    "columns": [ 
        {
            "title":"Favorite",
            "type":"CHECKBOX",
            "symbol":"STAR"
        }, 
        {
            "title":"Primary Column", 
            "primary":true,
            "type":"TEXT_NUMBER"
        }
    ]
}
```

That is the example body for the request from the Smartsheet API docs [here](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#create-sheet).

Note, this will create a blank sheet and once you have that you can use [Add Row](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#add-rows) requests to add data to the newly created sheet.